# How to provide comment to git pull merge message

Tags: git, git-pull

my automation fails because `git pull` expects a reply (merge message).
I saw I can use the `--no-edit` flag which is not recommended.
Instead I would like to actually provide a message to it during the pull.
Of course, if there is a conflict - to exit with failure.

How to do that ?

Comment: If you are writing a script (automating things), I recommend avoiding `git pull` entirely: break it down into `git fetch` and whatever second Git command you intend to use. Otherwise you'll be affected by the user's configuration, in particular merge vs rebase. (Of course, if you *want* to be affected by the user's configuration, using `git pull` is OK.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run :

```
git pull --no-commit && git commit -m ...
```